# HTML5 write to file opened via drag file event

Tags: html, html5-filesystem

We can drag a file to browser and read it's content. But is there any way where we can write back to same file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **No**.  The browser cannot arbitrarily write a file to the local file system.  When a user drags a file onto the browser, this is user-driven action whereby the user's action grants the browser approval to access the file. However, that file is simply opened by the browser for read-only purposes; it cannot make change and save it back.

The "File System API" **does not provide read/write access to the client/local file system**. This is probably *the* biggest misunderstanding about the File System API, probably because the name of the API give the impression that it can do something it really can't.

I covered this more fully in [my reply on **JS Filesystem API: accessing JS FileEntry's on local system?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288795/js-filesystem-api-accessing-js-fileentrys-on-local-system/18372519#18372519).

Comment: Yes i can see. file read/write term was actually creating confusion about this. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: You're quite welcome, Vinay.  I should point out that while you cannot directly write to the user's system, the File System API can be used to push a file for the user to accept as a download. So the user can load the file into the client, the client can modify it, and you can offer it as a download. (I hope that makes sense). See this thread: [downloading a sandboxed file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995826/html5-filesystem-api-downloading-a-sandboxed-file)